# Eclipse Java - An Error has occured (Win10)

Tags: java, eclipse, crash, windows-10, startup

I was just trying to install Eclipse on my new Windows 10 PC, but things go wrong. I can't open it, not even once. I don't have any workspace either (another topic answer that you have to delete something in it, but i can't).

I just installed JAVA 8 and Java JDK 12 and the last version of Eclipse, i don't know how can it be wrong..

```
!SESSION 2019-09-13 13:07:40.749 -----------------------------------------------
eclipse.buildId=4.5.0.I20150603-2000
java.version=12.0.2
java.vendor=Oracle Corporation
BootLoader constants: OS=win32, ARCH=x86_64, WS=win32, NL=fr_FR
Framework arguments:  -product org.eclipse.epp.package.java.product
Command-line arguments:  -os win32 -ws win32 -arch x86_64 -product org.eclipse.epp.package.java.product -clean

!ENTRY org.eclipse.ant.core 4 0 2019-09-13 13:07:43.093
!MESSAGE FrameworkEvent ERROR
!STACK 0
org.osgi.framework.BundleException: Could not resolve module: org.eclipse.ant.core [57]
  Unresolved requirement: Require-Bundle: org.eclipse.core.variables; bundle-version="[3.1.0,4.0.0)"
    -> Bundle-SymbolicName: org.eclipse.core.variables; bundle-version="3.2.800.v20130819-1716"; singleton:="true"
       org.eclipse.core.variables [83]
         Unresolved requirement: Require-Bundle: org.eclipse.core.runtime; bundle-version="[3.3.0,4.0.0)"
           -> Bundle-SymbolicName: org.eclipse.core.runtime; bundle-version="3.11.0.v20150405-1723"; singleton:="true"
              org.eclipse.core.runtime [80]
                Unresolved requirement: Require-Bundle: org.eclipse.core.jobs; bundle-version="[3.2.0,4.0.0)"; visibility:="reexport"
                  -> Bundle-SymbolicName: org.eclipse.core.jobs; bundle-version="3.7.0.v20150330-2103"; singleton:="true"
                     org.eclipse.core.jobs [75]
                       Unresolved requirement: Require-Capability: osgi.ee; filter:="(&(osgi.ee=JavaSE)(version=1.7))"

    at org.eclipse.osgi.container.Module.start(Module.java:434)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.container.ModuleContainer$ContainerStartLevel.incStartLevel(ModuleContainer.java:1582)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.container.ModuleContainer$ContainerStartLevel.incStartLevel(ModuleContainer.java:1561)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.container.ModuleContainer$ContainerStartLevel.doContainerStartLevel(ModuleContainer.java:1533)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.container.ModuleContainer$ContainerStartLevel.dispatchEvent(ModuleContainer.java:1476)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.container.ModuleContainer$ContainerStartLevel.dispatchEvent(ModuleContainer.java:1)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.eventmgr.EventManager.dispatchEvent(EventManager.java:230)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.eventmgr.EventManager$EventThread.run(EventManager.java:340)

!ENTRY org.eclipse.ant.launching 4 0 2019-09-13 13:07:43.093
!MESSAGE FrameworkEvent ERROR
!STACK 0
org.osgi.framework.BundleException: Could not resolve module: org.eclipse.ant.launching [58]
  Unresolved requirement: Require-Bundle: org.eclipse.core.runtime; bundle-version="[3.5.0,4.0.0)"
    -> Bundle-SymbolicName: org.eclipse.core.runtime; bundle-version="3.11.0.v20150405-1723"; singleton:="true"
       org.eclipse.core.runtime [80]
         Unresolved requirement: Require-Bundle: org.eclipse.core.jobs; bundle-version="[3.2.0,4.0.0)"; visibility:="reexport"
           -> Bundle-SymbolicName: org.eclipse.core.jobs; bundle-version="3.7.0.v20150330-2103"; singleton:="true"
              org.eclipse.core.jobs [75]
                Unresolved requirement: Require-Capability: osgi.ee; filter:="(&(osgi.ee=JavaSE)(version=1.7))"

    at org.eclipse.osgi.container.Module.start(Module.java:434)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.container.ModuleContainer$ContainerStartLevel.incStartLevel(ModuleContainer.java:1582)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.container.ModuleContainer$ContainerStartLevel.incStartLevel(ModuleContainer.java:1561)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.container.ModuleContainer$ContainerStartLevel.doContainerStartLevel(ModuleContainer.java:1533)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.container.ModuleContainer$ContainerStartLevel.dispatchEvent(ModuleContainer.java:1476)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.container.ModuleContainer$ContainerStartLevel.dispatchEvent(ModuleContainer.java:1)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.eventmgr.EventManager.dispatchEvent(EventManager.java:230)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.eventmgr.EventManager$EventThread.run(EventManager.java:340)

!ENTRY org.eclipse.ant.ui 4 0 2019-09-13 13:07:43.093
!MESSAGE FrameworkEvent ERROR
!STACK 0
org.osgi.framework.BundleException: Could not resolve module: org.eclipse.ant.ui [59]
  Unresolved requirement: Require-Bundle: org.eclipse.ant.core; bundle-version="[3.2.0,4.0.0)"
    -> Bundle-SymbolicName: org.eclipse.ant.core; bundle-version="3.4.0.v20150428-1928"; singleton:="true"
       org.eclipse.ant.core [57]
         Unresolved requirement: Require-Bundle: org.eclipse.core.variables; bundle-version="[3.1.0,4.0.0)"
           -> Bundle-SymbolicName: org.eclipse.core.variables; bundle-version="3.2.800.v20130819-1716"; singleton:="true"
              org.eclipse.core.variables [83]
                Unresolved requirement: Require-Bundle: org.eclipse.core.runtime; bundle-version="[3.3.0,4.0.0)"
                  -> Bundle-SymbolicName: org.eclipse.core.runtime; bundle-version="3.11.0.v20150405-1723"; singleton:="true"
                     org.eclipse.core.runtime [80]
                       Unresolved requirement: Require-Bundle: org.eclipse.core.jobs; bundle-version="[3.2.0,4.0.0)"; visibility:="reexport"
                         -> Bundle-SymbolicName: org.eclipse.core.jobs; bundle-version="3.7.0.v20150330-2103"; singleton:="true"
                            org.eclipse.core.jobs [75]
                              Unresolved requirement: Require-Capability: osgi.ee; filter:="(&(osgi.ee=JavaSE)(version=1.7))"
  Unresolved requirement: Require-Bundle: org.eclipse.ui.workbench.texteditor; bundle-version="[3.5.0,4.0.0)"; resolution:="optional"
    -> Bundle-SymbolicName: org.eclipse.ui.workbench.texteditor; bundle-version="3.9.100.v20141023-1946"; singleton:="true"
       org.eclipse.ui.workbench.texteditor [403]
         Unresolved requirement: Require-Bundle: org.eclipse.core.runtime; bundle-version="[3.5.0,4.0.0)"
           -> Bundle-SymbolicName: org.eclipse.core.runtime; bundle-version="3.11.0.v20150405-1723"; singleton:="true"
  Unresolved requirement: Require-Bundle: org.eclipse.ui.ide; bundle-version="[3.2.0,4.0.0)"; resolution:="optional"
    -> Bundle-SymbolicName: org.eclipse.ui.ide; bundle-version="3.11.0.v20150510-1749"; singleton:="true"
       org.eclipse.ui.ide [389]
         Unresolved requirement: Require-Bundle: org.eclipse.core.runtime; bundle-version="[3.2.0,4.0.0)"
           -> Bundle-SymbolicName: org.eclipse.core.runtime; bundle-version="3.11.0.v20150405-1723"; singleton:="true"
         Unresolved requirement: Require-Bundle: org.eclipse.core.resources; bundle-version="[3.7.0,4.0.0)"; resolution:="optional"
           -> Bundle-SymbolicName: org.eclipse.core.resources; bundle-version="3.10.0.v20150423-0755"; singleton:="true"
              org.eclipse.core.resources [78]
                Unresolved requirement: Require-Bundle: org.eclipse.ant.core; bundle-version="[3.1.0,4.0.0)"; resolution:="optional"
                  -> Bundle-SymbolicName: org.eclipse.ant.core; bundle-version="3.4.0.v20150428-1928"; singleton:="true"
                Unresolved requirement: Require-Bundle: org.eclipse.core.expressions; bundle-version="[3.2.0,4.0.0)"
                  -> Bundle-SymbolicName: org.eclipse.core.expressions; bundle-version="3.5.0.v20150421-2214"; singleton:="true"
                     org.eclipse.core.expressions [69]
                       Unresolved requirement: Require-Bundle: org.eclipse.core.runtime; bundle-version="[3.3.0,4.0.0)"
                         -> Bundle-SymbolicName: org.eclipse.core.runtime; bundle-version="3.11.0.v20150405-1723"; singleton:="true"
  Unresolved requirement: Require-Bundle: org.eclipse.jface.text; bundle-version="[3.5.0,4.0.0)"; resolution:="optional"
    -> Bundle-SymbolicName: org.eclipse.jface.text; bundle-version="3.10.0.v20150603-1752"
       org.eclipse.jface.text [222]
         Unresolved requirement: Require-Bundle: org.eclipse.core.runtime; bundle-version="[3.5.0,4.0.0)"
           -> Bundle-SymbolicName: org.eclipse.core.runtime; bundle-version="3.11.0.v20150405-1723"; singleton:="true"
  Unresolved requirement: Require-Bundle: org.eclipse.ui.editors; bundle-version="[3.2.0,4.0.0)"; resolution:="optional"
    -> Bundle-SymbolicName: org.eclipse.ui.editors; bundle-version="3.9.0.v20150213-1939"; singleton:="true"
       org.eclipse.ui.editors [386]
         Unresolved requirement: Require-Bundle: org.eclipse.core.runtime; bundle-version="[3.7.0,4.0.0)"
           -> Bundle-SymbolicName: org.eclipse.core.runtime; bundle-version="3.11.0.v20150405-1723"; singleton:="true"
  Unresolved requirement: Require-Bundle: org.eclipse.ui.views; bundle-version="[3.2.0,4.0.0)"; resolution:="optional"
    -> Bundle-SymbolicName: org.eclipse.ui.views; bundle-version="3.8.0.v20150422-0725"; singleton:="true"
       org.eclipse.ui.views [398]
         Unresolved requirement: Require-Bundle: org.eclipse.core.runtime; bundle-version="[3.11.0,4.0.0)"
           -> Bundle-SymbolicName: org.eclipse.core.runtime; bundle-version="3.11.0.v20150405-1723"; singleton:="true"

    at org.eclipse.osgi.container.Module.start(Module.java:434)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.container.ModuleContainer$ContainerStartLevel.incStartLevel(ModuleContainer.java:1582)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.container.ModuleContainer$ContainerStartLevel.incStartLevel(ModuleContainer.java:1561)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.container.ModuleContainer$ContainerStartLevel.doContainerStartLevel(ModuleContainer.java:1533)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.container.ModuleContainer$ContainerStartLevel.dispatchEvent(ModuleContainer.java:1476)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.container.ModuleContainer$ContainerStartLevel.dispatchEvent(ModuleContainer.java:1)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.eventmgr.EventManager.dispatchEvent(EventManager.java:230)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.eventmgr.EventManager$EventThread.run(EventManager.java:340)
in.java:1488)
```

And that goes on..

Comment: Do you have JAVA_HOME defined and is this added to Path system variable ?

Comment: Your Eclipse is too old (Eclipse Mars 4.5). Use the current Eclipse 2019-06 to run with modern versions of Java.

Comment: I don't know, how can i add JAVA_HOME to the path system variable ? I know where are the system variables but don't know how to add JAVA_HOME specifically

Comment: My Eclipse is too old ? That was the first on the website.. god.. Thank, i'll try to find the latest !

Comment: What website? https://www.eclipse.org/downloads/ is the official site and that offers 2019-06. Your log shows `eclipse.buildId=4.5.0.I20150603-2000` which is Eclipse Mars from 2015

Comment: That was this exact website. I really don't understand how could i missed this... Well thank you

Answer (score 0):

That's the problem: Unresolved requirement: Require-Capability: osgi.ee; filter:="(&(osgi.ee=JavaSE)(version=1.7))"

Try installing [Java 7](https://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/downloads/java-archive-downloads-javase7-521261.html) first, maybe this resolves the problem.

Comment: For a new install it is far better to use the up to date Eclipse rather than trying to make an old release work.

Comment: I'm talking about the Java version, not Eclipse

Comment: Yes but OP already has Java 12 which will work fine with the up to date Eclipse. No need to install an out of date Java.

Comment: He/She has JDK 12 not the Java SE 12... I'm talking about the Java SE version

Comment: The JDK will work fine, in fact it is better for Eclipse as it contains the source.

Answer (score 0):

Add JAVA_HOME

https://javatutorial.net/set-java-home-windows-10

Install the latest Eclipse as it appears you have an older version

[https://www.eclipse.org/downloads/[2](https://www.eclipse.org/downloads/)

Install JDK 8 **This is optional it should work with JDK 12**

[Link to Download JDK 8](https://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/downloads/jdk8-downloads-2133151.html)